# Responsive banner image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive website which has a large banner image which spans edge to edge.  The problem is that its supposed to be a static height regardless of the screen size.  So when I set the image to width:100% it looks great in full size, but as soon as I start to shrink the screen the image gets shorter then the width that it needs to be.  How can I set this up so that the image height appears to never change and when the screen size is smaller then the image size it zooms in and crops the edges?

http://bit.ly/1qxmZir

HTML

```
<div id="hd-img">
    <img src="http://72.52.242.20/~camacoll/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/inner-hd.jpg"> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hd-img {
    max-height: 352px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -200%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: add  `min-width: ???px` to your CSS for the image, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/7CHbq/).

```
/* CSS */

#hd-img {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hd-img img {
    /* Optional max width: 600px; */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't expand the image all the way across the page.

Comment: Ah, that can be fixed. You need to specify the width of the internal image to be it's native size I.E 1980px. Or use a media query break point at the minimum width you wish to the image to adhere to.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
background-image:url(../images/header-bannerbg.png);background-position:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:580px;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I am not using background-image here.